# Copyright-free maps for journal figures

Tags: publications, copyright, graphics

I am writing an epidemiology paper for an academic journal, and would like to have a figure showing the map of a geographical region of interest.

My current map was generated with OpenStreetMap data, from the `get_stamenmap` function provided by the `ggmap` package in R.

However, such maps have [copyrights](https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright), and they won't be accepted by most academic journals I am interested in publishing in.
Does anyone know some good tools to produce pretty, copyright-free maps and possibly programmatically? Bonus points if they are produced through R.

I would also appreciate any other map-related hints or suggestions.

Comment: You can google "copyright free maps".  Are there features missing from these that you must have?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would like to add some pins to the maps at  custom (latitude, longitude) cohordinates. Ideally this would be done programmatically, but in the worst case scenario I could manually add them

Comment: Having to credit someone is very unlikely to be a bar to publishing. I would make sure this is actually the case

Comment: I agree fully with @NicolasFormichella - OpenStreetMaps tells you what you do to use a map generated using their data. You credit it in a footnote as they state. Perhaps you should (a) see how other people's maps are created/credited, and (b) ask the journal how they want it handled.

Comment: There is even an example in the copyright page, on how to fullfil the credit requirement for printed works

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful feedback. I may have misunderstood the copyrights requirements from the journals and will ask them if using OpenStreetMaps is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is a non-issue because Openstreetmap [allows](https://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/Licence/Attribution_Guidelines#Books,_magazines,_and_printed_maps) reusing maps with the only requirement to add a notice, for instance in a footnote or in the acknowledgments. So OP can continue using those maps, and they will be accepted by academic journals.

Answer (score -1):

[Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) is an OpenSource JavaScript Library to make and publish maps. You can use Leaflet through Python using [folium](https://pypi.org/project/folium/) library or with [R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/2.1.2).

Comment: Leaflet will still need to source data, so attribution/copyright is still an issue.